# Dirty check for combo box

Tags: extjs

I have a popup in which I have a dropdown. When I change the value of the dropdown to some other value it shows the orange triangle of the dirty check, but if I change the value of the drop down back to the previous value, the dirty check mark is still shown.

If the value is changed back to the original value in the dropdown, I want the dropdown to not show the dirty check mark.

Sharing my code

```
columns: {
    defaults: {
        align: 'left',
        flex: 2
    },
    items: [{
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            localized: {
                text: 'commonTranslations.function'
            },
            items: [{
                iconCls: 'iwp-icon-gen_edit',
                handler: 'onEditClick',

                getTip: function() {
                    return I18n.get('commonIconTranslations.penReleaseConcepts')
                }
            }],
            align: 'center',
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            localized: {
                text: 'commonTranslations.description'
            },
            dataIndex: 'title',
            renderer: CommonRendererUtils.htmlEncode
        },
        {
            localized: {
                text: 'commonTranslations.fileName'
            },
            dataIndex: 'filename',
            renderer: CommonRendererUtils.htmlEncode
        },
        {
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            localized: {
                text: 'commonTranslations.file'
            },
            items: [{
                getClass: function(v, metadata, r) {
                    if (!r.get('filename')) {
                        return 'x-hidden'
                    } else {
                        return 'iwp-icon-zeb_folder'
                    }
                },
                getTip: function() {
                    return I18n.get('commonIconTranslations.halfOpenFolder')
                },
                handler: 'onDownloadClick'
            }],
            align: 'center',
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            localized: {
                text: 'commonTranslations.source'
            },
            dataIndex: 'source',
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            localized: {
                text: 'details.tabview.scope.contents.release.main.uploadDate'
            },
            dataIndex: 'changeDate',
            xtype: 'dynamicTimestampColumn'
        },
        {
            localized: {
                text: 'details.tabview.scope.contents.release.main.uploadBy'
            },
            dataIndex: 'changeUser',
            xtype: 'usercolumn'
        },
        {
            localized: {
                text: 'commonTranslations.status'
            },
            /*-----facing issue for the column*/
            dataIndex: 'status',
            renderer: function(value) {
                return value.germanDescription;
            }

        },
        {
            localized: {
                text: 'commonTranslations.changeReason'
            },
            dataIndex: 'changeReason',
            renderer: CommonRendererUtils.htmlEncode
        },
        {
            localized: {
                text: 'commonTranslations.modulOrg'
            },
            dataIndex: 'modulOrgs',
            renderer: function(value, metaData, record) {
                if (record.isModified(metaData.column.dataIndex)) {
                    console.log("modified 9999999" + record.isModified(metaData.column.dataIndex));
                    metaData.tdCls += 'x-grid-dirty-cell';
                }
                var formattedValue = "";
                if (value) {
                    value.forEach(function(modulOrg) {
                        formattedValue += modulOrg.modulOrg + ", ";
                    });
                }
                return formattedValue.substring(0, formattedValue.length - 2);
            },
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            localized: {
                text: 'details.tabview.scope.contents.release.main.historyIndex'
            },
            dataIndex: 'historyIndex',
            flex: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: See the documentation for combobox. There is a method `isDirty()` that should be comparing the original value to the new value. Your original value is not being set correctly for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have too much code for this. Anyways there is a change event listener that you can add to your dropdown as follows:

```
listeners:{
    change:'combochange'
}
```

Now you can write this combochange function inside your controller or you can defined this function inside your view only.

```
combochange:function(field,newValue,oldValue,e){
// Inside this function you will get both the values of the dropdown of 
yours where newValue is the value currently selected and oldValue is the 
previous value. So inside this function according to your conditions you 
can put a check that if the old and newvalue matches then not to show the 
orange triangle.
}
```

Let me know if any issue. Happy Learning :)